# How to determine during the build which exactly version of dependency is used

Tags: android, gradle

I want to display exact versions of my app's dependencies in the "About" screen. In `build.config` I'm using wildcards like `compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.+'` for dependencies, but the exact version used will be, say, `16.0.1`. Is there a way to get all the dependencies listed with their actual versions and, for example, put them into `BuildConfig` file so that I can read them in app's runtime?

Comment: There's an open source plugin that prints the exact dependency versions - https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin. I would take a look at that, and then adapt the behaviour to add the version to your build config file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the `dependencyReport` task from the [project reports plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/project_reports_plugin.html)

Otherwise you could do something like this:

```
task buildConfig << {
   new File("$buildDir/BuildConfig").withWriter { out ->
        configurations.runtime.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { dep -> 
            out.writeLine(dep.moduleVersion.id.toString()) 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code exactly, and got the following error:
`Execution failed for task ':buildConfig'.
> Could not find property 'runtime' on configuration container.`
Any ideas what could that mean?

Comment: are you using the java plugin? (Also my main recommendation was to use the reports plugin)