# Gradle project configuration is not visible from defaultConfig

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to list all of mine Android Gradle project's actual dependencies in the BuildConfig.java (see [How to determine during the build which exactly version of dependency is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24290936/371804)). For that I'm using code similar to this:

```
def getProjectAndBuildscriptDependencies() {
    project.allprojects.collectMany{ proj ->
        def configurations = (proj.configurations + proj.buildscript.configurations)
        configurations.collectMany { it.allDependencies }
    }.findAll { it instanceof ExternalDependency }
}

private def resolveActualDependencyVersion(Dependency dependency) {
    def version = dependency.version
    boolean mightBeDynamicVersion = version != null && (version.endsWith('+') || version.endsWith(']') || version.endsWith(')') || version.startsWith('latest.'))
    if (!mightBeDynamicVersion){
        return version
    }

    def actualVersion = resolveWithAllRepositories{
        project.configurations.detachedConfiguration(dependency).resolvedConfiguration.lenientConfiguration
            .getFirstLevelModuleDependencies(org.gradle.api.specs.Specs.SATISFIES_ALL).find()?.moduleVersion ?: version
    }
    return actualVersion
}
```

This function is supposed to gather all the dependencies I have. If I call it from some task, it does what it has to:

```
task printCurrentDependencies << {
    def current = getProjectAndBuildscriptDependencies()

    def currentVersions = [:]
    current.each { dependency ->
        def actualVersion = resolveActualDependencyVersion(dependency)
        currentVersions.put(keyOf(dependency), actualVersion)
    }
}
```

So that `currentVersions` contain **all the dependencies** with their actual version.

However when I call it from `defaultConfig` of `android` section, **it only gives me one dependency**, which is the Gradle itself.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {        
        buildConfigField "int", "depsCount", getProjectDependencies().size().toString()
    }
}
```

This difference in behavior is confusing me. Why this happens, and how to fix it and achieve what I really want?